# Is overwriting a procedure's local variable allowed inside of a loop?

Tags: assembly, intel, masm32

I established a local variable in a procedure using LOCAL. I am using a loop with string primitive to get BYTE values from a string and convert the ASCII values of numerals into the real value of the numerals. I want to add up the value of each numeral by place and store these values in a local variable, but when I try to do this I get a runtime error "read access violation. summation was 0xFFFFFFF8". summation is the name of the local variable.

So, I cannot use the ADD instruction or the MOV instruction with summation inside of the loop, but outside of the loop I can perform operations with this local variable.

So, I am wondering if MASM restricts access to the local variable within a loop or if I am doing something wrong here, and if access to the variable is restricted, is there a way I can access the variable in the loop? Maybe pushing the OFFSET to the stack before entering the loop?

I checked the stack in the debugger and nothing appears to be awry there and PUSH and POP is balanced in the procedure.

The code I have is very long already for this program. So, I opted to just ask the general question, but I can add some code segments if requested.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Yes you can of course change local variables any way you want. You are doing something wrong. Use your debugger to look at the faulting instruction, verify it is what you want it to be and that the operands are valid.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. I accidently overwrote EBP register in one line of code when I meant to use EBX. I feel stupid now